# Union All Won't work in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure1]
 @YearToGet int

AS
Select Division, SDESCR,        
    DYYYY, 
 Sum(APRICE) ASofSales, 
    Sum(PARTY) AS ASofPAX,        
    Sum(NetAmount) ASofNetSales,        
    Sum(InsAmount) ASofInsSales,        
    Sum(CancelRevenue) ASofCXSales,        
    Sum(OtherAmount) ASofOtherSales,        
    Sum(CXVALUE) ASofCXValue  
From dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
Where Booked <= CONVERT(int,DateAdd(year, @YearToGet - Year(getdate()),                   
                DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 1, getdate()), 0) ) ) and
(DYYYY = @YearToGet)
Group By SDESCR, DYYYY, Division
Having (DYYYY = @YearToGet)  
Order By Division, SDESCR, DYYYY 

union all

SELECT     
DIVISION, 
SDESCR,
DYYYY, 
SUM(APRICE) AS YESales, 
SUM(PARTY) AS YEPAX, 
SUM(NetAmount) AS YENetSales,
SUM(InsAmount)  AS YEInsSales, 
SUM(CancelRevenue) AS YECXSales, 
SUM(OtherAmount) AS YEOtherSales,
SUM(CXVALUE) AS YECXValue
FROM         dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
Where (DYYYY=@YearToGet)
GROUP BY SDESCR, DYYYY, DIVISION
ORDER BY DIVISION, SDESCR, DYYYY
```

The error I am getting is

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure
>   MyStoredProcedure1, Line 36 Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'union'.

But my goal here is the user inputs a year for example 2009, my first query will get all the sales made in 2009 to the same date it is was yesterday 12/23/2009, while the second query is getting 2009 totals up to dec 31 2009.

I want the columns to be side by side not in one column

Comment: And the **error message** you're getting is?? And your question is???

Comment: I don't think you can have `ORDER BY` on your partial `SELECT`'s, when you're trying to get them together with a `UNION ALL`; try removing the `ORDER BY` from the first `SELECT` - does it work then?

Comment: you were right marc but for some reason everythin is displayed in the same columns for example YESales and AsofSales are still under the same column

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a union here? Do you really want the procedure to return two separate record sets instead?

Comment: if it returns two separate record sets how does it work in a gridview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to show the data side by side, then you don't want to use UNION.  Instead, you could use derived tables or CTE's and then join the 2 queries on SDESCR, DYYYY, Division.  Looking at your queries, the only (apparent) difference is that one includes a where clause on the Booked column.  We can move this where clause criteria in to the sum aggregate which should allow us to get all of the data we need in one pass through the tables.  Something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure1]
 @YearToGet int
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

Declare @Booked Int
Set @Booked = CONVERT(int,DateAdd(year, @YearToGet - Year(getdate()),                   
                DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 1, getdate()), 0) ) )

Select Division, 
       SDESCR,        
       DYYYY, 
       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then APRICE End) ASofSales, 
       SUM(APRICE) AS YESales, 

       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then PARTY End) AS ASofPAX,        
       SUM(PARTY) AS YEPAX, 

       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then NetAmount End) ASofNetSales,        
       SUM(NetAmount) AS YENetSales,

       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then InsAmount End) ASofInsSales,        
       SUM(InsAmount)  AS YEInsSales, 

       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then CancelRevenue End) ASofCXSales,        
       SUM(CancelRevenue) AS YECXSales, 

       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then OtherAmount End) ASofOtherSales,        
       SUM(OtherAmount) AS YEOtherSales,

       Sum(Case When Booked <= @Booked Then CXVALUE End) ASofCXValue,
       SUM(CXVALUE) AS YECXValue
From   dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
Where  DYYYY = @YearToGet
Group By SDESCR, DYYYY, Division
Order By Division, SDESCR, DYYYY
```

I encourage you to try this procedure.  I think it will return the data you are looking for.

Edited to put Less than or equal for the Booked criteria.

Comment: ugh so close but my asof columns are retuning null values : /

Comment: Did you notice that I declare a local variable and set it at the top of the procedure?

Comment: I just noticed that the original where clause has Booked less than or equal.  Changing that in my post.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: yay! i wish i could up this like 1000

Answer (score 3):

Remove the first `order by`, just before the `union all`. For sanity, keep the column names the same. The second `order by` applies to all the rows.

**BTW**, what you want is much closer to this. Did not test it, but based on your description this should be close.

```
;
with
q_00 as (
select
      DIVISION
    , SDESCR
    , DYYYY
    , sum(APRICE)        as ofSales 
    , sum(PARTY)         as ofPAX        
    , sum(NetAmount)     as ofNetSales        
    , sum(InsAmount)     as ofInsSales        
    , sum(CancelRevenue) as ofCXSales        
    , sum(OtherAmount)   as ofOtherSales        
    , sum(CXVALUE)       as ofCXValue  
from dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
where Booked <= CONVERT(int,DateAdd(year, @YearToGet - Year(getdate()), DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 1, getdate()), 0)))
  and DYYYY = @YearToGet
group by DIVISION, SDESCR, DYYYY 
),
q_01 as (
select     
      DIVISION 
    , SDESCR
    , DYYYY 
    , sum(APRICE)        as YESales 
    , sum(PARTY)         as YEPAX 
    , sum(NetAmount)     as YENetSales
    , sum(InsAmount)     as YEInsSales 
    , sum(CancelRevenue) as YECXSales 
    , sum(OtherAmount)   as YEOtherSales
    , sum(CXVALUE)       as YECXValue
from  dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
where DYYYY=@YearToGet
group by DIVISION, SDESCR, DYYYY 
)
select
      a.DIVISION 
    , a.SDESCR
    , a.DYYYY
    , ofSales 
    , ofPAX        
    , ofNetSales        
    , ofInsSales        
    , ofCXSales        
    , ofOtherSales        
    , ofCXValue  
    , YESales 
    , YEPAX 
    , YENetSales
    , YEInsSales 
    , YECXSales 
    , YEOtherSales
    , YECXValue
from q_00 as a
join q_01 as b on (b.DIVISION = a.DIVISION and b.SDESCR = a.SDESCR and b.DYYYY = a.DYYYY) 
order by a.DIVISION, a.SDESCR, a.DYYYY ;
```

Comment: bare with me im an sql tard. whyd i get an error at ; the first line

Comment: @MyHeadHurts, the semicolon is required for common table expressions (CTE's).  CTE's were first introduced in SQL2005.  If you are using SQL2000, then you would get an error.  If you are using SQL2000, then you should include that information on all of your questions.  There are quite a few differences between SQL2000 and newer versions.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts, sorry did not properly get the previous question -- you are using SQL Server 2005 as tagged?

Answer (score 2):

Requirements for UNION include that the data types be similar, that each `SELECT` contains the same number of columns, and that the columns appear in the same order in both `SELECT`s.

**Edit**: to answer your question in a comment: If you want to have the columns appear side by side, you have to put filler columns in both SELECTs.

```
Select Division, SDESCR, DYYYY, 
Sum(APRICE) ASofSales, 
'' AS YESales,
Sum(PARTY) AS ASofPAX,  
'' AS YEPAX
```

... and so on, with identical columns in both `SELECTS`, just some columns are empty in one `SELECT` or the other.

**Another edit:** The column names (or aliases) don't have to be the same in both SELECTS, but using different aliases will help you to distinguish which column is which. On the aggregate fields (SUM), if you don't supply an alias, figuring out what the column represents could be tricky. If you alias the columns as you have done in your SQL, and interleave the empty string columns, I think you will get the result you seek.

Comment: is this even if i want them to be listed side by side and not underneath one another?

Comment: not the same names, they can be different names but have to be the same ordering and number of fields and have compatible types

Comment: so close i still used different names but then i got shot with this error as soon as i thought it was going to work 
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure MyStoredProcedure1, Line 22
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: My head is starting to hurt, too. I believe you should have 17 columns in all. Perhaps start simpler and try to get just the first few columns working. Then when that is working, add the rest of the columns.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is not the UNION ALL or that the column aliases are not named the same.  The problem is with the ORDER BY line just above the UNION ALL line.  If you remove that line, your query will run.  This won't list the data side by side like you wanted, but it will allow the query to run.